# How do you create a process list ''file'' like process.txt on windows?

Tags: text-processing

I would really like to know whether there is something similar to process.txt on ubuntu.
You know, an overview of all of your processes as a text-file in order to E-Mail it to others or load it on an USB-Stick for example.And if you know whether it exists or not, tell me how to create it please, which commands you have to use and so on.

Thank you for your help!

- bagara

Answer (score 2):

```
ps -eo comm,pid,%cpu,%mem --sort -%cpu > procs.txt
```

You can see the *STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS* in the manual of `ps` from man page with `man ps` and choose what to display

Answer (score 0):

I think that you meant something like this:

```
ps aux > process.txt
```